# Does Microsoft have the tools for writing of the automated tests for Office 365 Online (Excel)?

Tags: office365, office-js, office-addins

We plan to cover our Excel Online add-in not only with text test cases for manual testing, but also with the automated tests.
Does Microsoft have any tools / libraries to help us with this task?

Answer (score 1):

While Microsoft doesn't have a published way of doing this, I strongly recommend you to take a look at UI testing, since add-ins are just regular webpages anyways. This method is tested (on add-ins as well, you may need to adjust a few things but it is entirely possible)

You could check out anything selenium based which would give you cross-browser compatibility.

I suggest you look into Puppeteer, Protractor, Cypress...

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but we do not have such tools. But it's a good idea that has been suggested at  [Office Developer Suggestion Box](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/34345651-add-in-developers-automated-testing-platform). Please vote it up.